# Python, cv2.estimateAffine3D - why do my output arguments remain unchanged?

Tags: python, opencv

Greetings to all with this my first-time question in this forum.

I have been trying to use estimateAffine3D, and I don't seem to be getting any results in the variables where they should be.

The (nearly) shortest bit of code to reproduce my problem is:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

X=array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]])
# the eight vertices of a unit cube
Y=array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,1]])
# the same cube scaled by 2 in the X direction (and no longer a cube)

# create the output variables and fill them with recognizable values:
MyAffine=array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 9]])
MyInLi=array([7,3,7])

# now fire estimateAffine3D:
cv.estimateAffine3D(src=X,dst=Y,out=MyAffine,inliers=MyInLi)

# NB I also tried this without the formal parameter names:
# cv.estimateAffine3D(X,Y,MyAffine,MyInLi)

# Now see what gives:
print "MyAffine=", MyAffine
print "MyInLi=", MyInLi
```

The two arrays, as printed out at the end of the code,
contain the same placeholder values they were created with.

I have spent a lot of time googling for any existing answers to similar questions, but those concerning estimateAffine3D concentrate, understandably, on cases where it does return *some* values (if not the ones the user expected), or where it throws an error - which is not my case.

I have also been looking at discussions of how Python passes arguments, but all I understood was that it passes them *differently* from anything I have known so far (C++, a little Pascal, and, centuries ago, Basic and Fortran). My failure to understand the Python way is probably the cause of my predicament, but what should I do differently?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment.

Comment: Unless there is some code in `cv.estimateAffine3D` that changes the arrays inplace then nothing would be changed, looking at the docs it returns `retval, out, inliers`so I imagine you would need to use the return values http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#estimateaffine3d

Comment: Thank you; yes I have just noticed that the function _returns_ some values, and this will likely solve my problem. But now out of pure curiosity: what is the point of the optional **out** and **inliers** arguments? If, upon exit from 'cv.estimateAffine3D', they do not contain any output from that function, are they meant to supply some _input_ to it? The documentation you pointed to seems to say that they are indeed meant for output, in parallel with the return values.

Comment: The documentation is not the greatest but I did a bit of searching and using the example from the tests.py I created np.zeros array with shape 3,4 and out did get modified http://pastebin.com/aDpHjhYz what may well be the issue is trying to change the dtype from int to float if you are passing ints

Comment: Great thanks. I have changed the initial values to `MyAffine=array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0]])


MyInLi=array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]], dtype=uint8)
`
and now I don't even have to rewrite my code to use the return values; the ouptut arguments work to specs.